# Install Ejabberd XMPP Server on AWS failing

Tags: amazon-ec2, xampp, ejabberd

I am trying to install Ejabberd on EC2.
I tried doing the following
`sudo Downloads/ejabberd-16.09-linux-x86_64-installer.run`
 ran this command,getting this error

> Downloads/ejabberd-16.09-linux-x86_64-installer.run: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'.
>   Downloads/ejabberd-16.09-linux-x86_64-installer.run: line 1:`'

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates a syntax error. You can use the following code to install the downloaded file.

```
cd Downloads
sudo ./ejabberd-16.09-linux-x86_64-installer.run
```